# What is the best font for Labeling in windows that is consistent with MaTeX fonts?

Tags: plotting, labeling, matex

I am using `MaTex` on windows and Ubuntu and for labeling, I use the font `Latin Modern Roman` which is completely consistent with the font generated by `MaTex` in Ubuntu but it gives different font on Windows?

here is the code and the results I got from Ubuntu18.04 MMA12.1.1 and windows10 MMA12.3:

```
     plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -5, 5}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", Black, 
    FontSize -> 16}, 
  FrameLabel -> (MaTeX[#, 
       Magnification -> 1.5] &) /@ {"\\delta(x) \\ -4 \\ 0\\ 4 ", 
     "\\beta_i(y)"}, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 300]
```

from win

[image]

from Ubuntu

[image]

you can see that on windows the ticks font are different from those numbers ($-4, 0, 4$) generated by `MaTex`. So, Is there a specific font in the windows that can generate the same font style as `Matex`?

Comment: This is covered in the documentation: please go through the tutorial which has a full section on the topic. On Windows, you need to refer to the font by a different name, which I don't recall. (EDIT: The docs say try "LM Roman 12".) You will need to find the correct name yourself by e.g. using a GUI font chooser and noting the name. I don't know why the same font appears under different names in different OSs.

Comment: And of course, you need to actually install this font before you can use it.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I am actually aware of the section in the documentation and try the font you mentioned in the documentation for windows but did not give the desired results, and that why I came here to seek help. I still don't understand how should I find the respective font? may you please elaborate?

Comment: Did you install the font (and after doing so, did you restart Mathematica)? Did you try the name suggested by the documentation, which is "LM Roman 12"?

Comment: yes, I did try the one you suggested but still did not give the desired results.

Comment: Which of the two (actually three) questions I asked in my last comment did you answer to?

Comment: sorry, I tried the font you mentioned in the comment "LM Roman 12"but did not give the desired results. I did not install any new fonts and even don't know how to do that in mathematica, and don't know which font exactly should I install.

Comment: "I did not install any new fonts" Well, then of course that's the problem. If you don't have a font installed on your system (note: you install it for Windows, not for Mathematica) then you can't use it. The documentation page I referred to has a link to where you can download the font, http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern

Comment: @Szabolcs, thank you very much, it is working perfectly now

Comment: Can you let me know what font name you had to use? I don't have Windows with a full TeX system available at the moment. Did "LM Roman 12" work? You can also suggest improvements to the documentation page I referenced, and I'll see if I can incorporate them into the next release. It is difficult to write useful documentation: if it's too terse, then it will be hard to understand. If it's too verbose, people won't read it. One needs to optimize for maximum informativeness in the minimum amount of space, which is hard.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I used the font "LM Roman 12" which I download from this web: https://www.1001fonts.com/latin-modern-roman-font.html. I will post it as an answer also in case someone faces the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Szabolcs, the font for windows is *Latin Modern* and we need to install this font on windows which can be installed from [this](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern) web. Then running this code on windows gives the desired results

```
  plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -5, 5}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Black, FontSize -> 22}, 
  FrameLabel -> (MaTeX[#, 
       FontSize -> 22] &) /@ {"\\delta(x) \\ -4 \\ 0\\ 4 ", 
     "\\beta_i(y)"}, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Comment: No, it is not correct to say that "the font is LM Roman 12". The font is called _Latin Modern_. This is the official website for this open-source font:  http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern I do not recommend getting it from other sources, especially not from sources like the one you linked, which often repackage open-source fonts in non-ideal ways.

Comment: Because of its advanced features, such as the availability of optical sizes, the _Latin Modern_ font will show up under different names on different operating systems. On Windows, the 12 pt optical size version appears to show up as "LM Roman 12". But you show _**not**_ be googling to download a font with this name. Once again, for future readers, get it from here: http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern

Comment: thanks @Szabolcs for the explanation, I will modify the  link and put the one you mentioned.